# Building Angular on EC2 server suddenly become very slow

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2

I always used to build Angular projects on server when I deploy. Today I tried building 5 times, the first 2 times works fine, but from the 3rd time the EC2 instance almost get freezes and no action or command entering is accepted other than ctrl + c. The website hosted on that instance also become unavailable until I stopped the building process. Where should I trouble shoot from?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is just another application consuming too much cpu or memory, which makes building angular would stuck all applications including itself. After stopping several applications it works fine. But still wish to know if there's a better way to trouble shoot a similar situation.